# Visual Studio can compile "extern alias" but VS Code cannot

Tags: c#, csproj

I have the following code in a .csproj file to define an alias for a `<PackageReference>` reference:

```
<Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'CoreCompat.System.Drawing'">
      <Aliases>CompatDrawing</Aliases>
    </ReferencePath>
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="CoreCompat.System.Drawing" Version="1.0.0-beta006" Alias="CompatDrawing" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Classes that have

```
using extern aliax CompatDrawing;
```

compile fine in Visual Studio but in VS Code I get:

> "The extern alias 'xxx' was not specified in a /reference ..." error was occured.

I think this problem is related to omnisharp but I cannot resolve it.

Comment: It's reported here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2342 and will be added soon.